# Why did Uraraka say this?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In **Chapter 21**, after the villains escaped from the USJ, the detective friend of All Might left the rest of their work to one of his officers, Sansa.

[image]

However, as he called Sansa by name, Uraraka remarked 'But he's not a dog...' Why did she say this? Or why would the mangaka show Uraraka making this comment after seeing Sansa?

Comment: Hmm.. wild guess, but this might be a reference to a common sense/misconception of "dog being loyal" vs "cat being selfish"?

Comment: @AkiTanaka Hmm..It's possible. First explanation I thought of was that it could be the name, that 'Sansa' is probably a common name for dogs in Japan, but I'm not sure if this is true and I can't find data to back what I thought of...